# Difference between Archna and pooja

Tags: rituals, worship

There are two "distinct" words used for worship, in Sanskrit, namely **अर्चना** and **पूजा**.
What is the basic difference between the two and their implementation, by a साधक (devotee) ?
Also, please tell scenarios/cases, when not exclusively one of them is used and not the other word.

Comment: ppujarchana is also used.But generally both mean the same in sanskrit

Comment: you could consult sanskritdictionary.com

Comment: @Pratimaputra, thanks for your timely reply. But I wanted to know difference in rituals, i.e., how is doing pooja different from doing archna, in practice

Comment: u r welcome. formally the word puja is used